# How to debug why a C# method does not return the expected value?

Tags: c#

I'm taking a C# course and I thought I knew how to do this but I guess not. Anyway it wants me to do these things:

> You will start by declaring a local int magicNumber variable and initializing it with the value in the myNumber input parameter. You then need to make a series of calculations, where each calculation uses the current value from your magicNumber variable and stores the result back into that same variable.
>
> Multiply the current value of magicNumber by 3 and store the result back in magicNumber
> Add 6 to the current value of magicNumber and store the result back in magicNumber
> Divide the current value of magicNumber by 3 and store the result back in magicNumber
> Subtract the original myNumber input from the current value of magicNumber, and store the result back in magicNumber

Here's my code.

```
private int findMagicNumber(int myNumber)
{
    // replace with student code
    return 0; //What is this???
    int magicNumber;
    magicNumber = magicNumber * 3;
    magicNumber = magicNumber + 6;
    magicNumber = magicNumber / 3;
    magicNumber = magicNumber - myNumber;
        
}
```

Comment: what's the questions?

Comment: your magicNumber will never execute since there's a return statement it will give control back to the caller of a method with 0 as a return value.

Comment: When writing titles, please **always write a useful one**. Some of the poor reception you are getting here may be due to this (and "please halp me" pleading may have annoyed readers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private int findMagicNumber(int myNumber)
 {
        int magicNumber = myNumber;
        magicNumber = magicNumber * 3;
        magicNumber = magicNumber + 6;
        magicNumber = magicNumber / 3;
        magicNumber = magicNumber - myNumber;
        return magicNumber;
 }
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description of what you changed (code-only solutions are discouraged here, even if you managed to get some upvotes for it).

Answer (score 2):

A few things that you should notice are:

- The codes that you wrote after the `return` will never execute, so the `findMagicNumber` method will always returns `0`
- The variable `magicNumber` have never initialized, so its value will be `0` by default.
- Choose a random number to initialize your magic number will make more sense.

In short your signature will be like the following:

```
public static Random rndSeed = new Random();
public static int findMagicNumber(int myNumber)
{
    int magicNumber = rndSeed.Next(1,100);
    magicNumber = magicNumber * 3;
    magicNumber = magicNumber + 6;
    magicNumber = magicNumber / 3;
    magicNumber = magicNumber - myNumber;
    return magicNumber;
}
```

Call the method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Try 1 :- {0} is my number, Magic Number will be {1}", 12,findMagicNumber(12));
// sample OutPut - Try 1 :- 12 is my number, Magic Number will be 63
```

Here is an [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1nsLYF) for you.